# Merging multiple Excel sheets into single Excel using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, spreadsheet

Is there a best way to merge multiple spreadsheets into single Excel file with multiple tabs, only using Apache poi or any open source libraries. I can find some  online, which does this by copying over cell by cell values and styles. But, Is there any even easier and efficient way to combine spreadsheets and attach them in single Excel file? (Ps- not interested in aspose library for this simple requirement)

Comment: "Is there any even easier and efficient way to combine spreadsheets and attach them in single Excel file?" No, there isn't any.

Comment: A Excel workbook consists of single sheet parts. But those sheet parts only contains numeric data and formulas and **references** to the styles, the shared strings and maybe pictures data and other data which are on workbook level. So while merging two workbooks the need is to decompose both workbooks and to new composite the styles part and the shared strings part and also reorganize the references in the sheets parts before adding all sheet parts to the new merged workbook. Not a simple task at all.

Comment: One of the row-by-row, cell-by-cell solutions for anyone who is looking https://gist.github.com/davidsommer/7805574